# E/jdwp﹕ REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=6/3 dataLen=12 id=0x00b218) when debugging Android

Tags: android, debugging

I keep getting these messages in logcat when I try to debug Android:

```
... E/jdwp﹕ REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=6/3 dataLen=12 id=0x00b218)
```

And the screens goes black (waiting for the debugger to attach I suppose?).

I have searched with Google to find an answer but I don't really find anything (that I understand) that seems to be the real culprit. Does anyone have a clue? Is it only the debugger that doesn't work, but also my code

Comment: did you tried run time debugging?

Comment: What do you mean? I press debug in IntelliJ and the normal Android debugging-process is initiated.

Comment: there are two types of debugging 1. you launch your app in debug mode. 2. you can attach debugger to already running app

Comment: OK. Well, if I uninstall the app and press debug in IntelliJ then the app installs, starts and then starts to debug. Then  it never gets to my breakpoint (in spawned thread). The screen is black and i get the above message.

Comment: so to try it at runtime launch your app normally and when you are about to reach that point just press the second icon after debug menu and then select your app

Comment: Which debug menu? Do you mean the run configuration menu/debug (while the app has already started)?

Comment: are you using android studio? If yes then to right of debug icon after leaving one icon you will see an icon with phone and debugger icon. use that and yes after app has started

Comment: OK. I did that. Debugger seems to work then, but it won't stop on break point in another spawned thread (even though that thread logs to console and I can see it its running).

Comment: then there is some error in your code

Comment: What kind of error could prevent debugger from stopping at a breakpoint?

Comment: run it without debugger

Comment: The code runs and prints to console when I do Log.v().